# Stop "Cucumber-rails required outside of env.rb..." message when cucumber-rails added to a gem's .gemspec

Tags: rubygems, cucumber, rails-engines

I have a gem and recently added `cucumber-rails` to the .gemspec:

```
  spec.add_development_dependency "cucumber-rails", "~> 1.4.3"
```

Now, when I package the gem with `rake build`, I get the following message:

```
WARNING: Cucumber-rails required outside of env.rb.  The rest of loading is being deferred 
until env.rb is called.  To avoid this warning, move 'gem 'cucumber-rails', 
:require => false' under only group :test in your Gemfile.  If already 
in the :test group, be sure you are specifying ':require => false'.
```

What's the best way to make this go away?  Should I be adding `cucumber-rails` to the gem's Gemfile instead of .gemspec?

Comment: Where are you requiring `cucumber-rails`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this, the following worked for me:

1. When cucumber-rails it is automatically required (and there is no way to disable this).  Remove cucumber-rails from the .gemspec.
2. Add it as a dependency in the gem's Gemfile instead.  My Gemfile currently looks like this:

   ```
   source 'https://rubygems.org'

   gemspec
   gem "cucumber-rails", "~> 1.4.3", require: false, group: :test
   ```

This makes the error go away when `rake build` is run.  There may be an issue when I publish the gem and add it to a Rails app.  I'll update my solution once I find out.

**Update**: I tried packaging the gem and loading it into a host application.  Everything looks good.